# Showing mapview on click in addressfield

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, abpersonviewcontroller

I have a class that subclasses `ABPersonViewController`. On clicking the address field in the PersonViewController, I need to show the corresponding address location in the mapview, just like what it is in the native addressbook. How can I implement this feature. Shouldn't this be a default feature in `ABPersonViewController`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check out the below links in which you have to send address from the address book

check out this two links in which one provide stack overflow answer [How to invoke iPhone Maps for Directions with Current Location as Start Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576768/how-to-invoke-iphone-maps-for-directions-with-current-location-as-start-address)
 and this one is tutorial from tutplus [mobtutplus](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-quick-tip-launching-maps-in-app/)

Comment: Now I am surprised about, how to handle the click event on the addresssfield in `ABPersonViewController`. If I have multiple addresses, how can I get that address on its click.

Comment: check out this links for your que http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320931/how-to-correctly-use-abpersonviewcontroller-with-abpeoplepickernavigationcontrol

Answer (score 0):

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];  
[app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Paris"]];
```

try this code,in place of Paris ,use own location name.