# ABPersonViewController does not have a navigationBar

Tags: ios, navigationbar, abpersonviewcontroller

I am writing an application that is based on UIViewController. It does not have a navigation bar.
My application works with AddressBook.
For now I use two things.

The first (select a people):

```
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

and the second (select a phone):

```
{
    ABPersonViewController *picker = [[[ABPersonViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    picker.personViewDelegate = self;
    picker.displayedPerson = person;
    picker.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty], nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

They are called in different functions.

In the first case when picker is displayed, it has a navigation bar with some buttons: Cancel etc.

In the second case another picker does not have a navigation bar. So, if I select the phone then it works but if I want to return without making a choice - I do not have a button "Back" or "Cancel".

How can I add the navigation bar in the second case?

I have tried to add another navigation controller and a viewcontroller as described below

[How to correctly use ABPersonViewController with ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to view Contact information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320931/how-to-correctly-use-abpersonviewcontroller-with-abpeoplepickernavigationcontrol)

this display the navigatiob bar but my application crashes after this.

and

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`, as the name suggests, is a navigation controller, so it has a navigation bar. `ABPersonViewController` is just a view controller, so it doesn't have a navigation bar of its own. You can put the instance of `ABPersonViewController` into a navigation controller yourself and present that, then it will have a navigation bar and you can add any buttons you need.

Comment: It seems to me that it is a key!

Comment: This works as necessary. Thank you!

    picker.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(ClosePeoplePicker)];

    UINavigationController *ctrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:picker];
    [self presentModalViewController:ctrl animated:YES];